# Invalid argument: 'using' must be a string extracting image source within an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm new about using python and selenium and I'm trying to get the image source from a website. I'm actually finding elements by the tag name, but I don't know if it's the right way.
Anyway it gives me an error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

Under this there's the code I wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

PATH = Service("/Users/fscozano/documenti/chromedriver-2.exe")

print("setup")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/random_apod.html")

tag = driver.find_element((By.TAG_NAME, "b")).getText()

print(tag)

driver.quit()
```

The error is in:

```
tag = driver.find_element((By.TAG_NAME, "b")).getText()
```

You can personally inspect the website because I really don't know how to solve this
Every type of help is appreciated :)

Comment: .getText() is Java you want .text for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image source is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/random_apod.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://apod.nasa.gov/apod']")))
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[normalize-space()='Astronomy Picture of the Day']//following::p[2]//a/img"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2111/MACSJ0138_Hubble_1080.jpg
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)